# Turn off Yahoo mail icons

Tags: yahoo-mail

I don't like to see the icon at each mail as in the below screenshot.

How can I turn that off?

[image]

Comment: Are those emails from Yahoo! or from the same type of organisation?

Answer (score 6):

If there is no way in the settings then there is really not much else you can do about it.

If you want to make a suggestion to yahoo they have a suggestions board here:
[Yahoo Suggestions Board](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/Suggestions-for-YDN)

Answer (score 4):

There is no official way to add/remove columns from the reading panes lists. That particular column sorts the mails by read/unread. Your only option is to find a custom script that removes the respective icons or the column entirely.

Answer (score -1):

select Settings-> Message Preview-> No avatars, no preview